# How to prevent future incomplete data from skewing a chart and it's trendline on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, plot, charts, google-sheets-formula

I prepared [this example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZKz02_O7xs4d79lJ1eHgpD621ELMZtaT4qknCuGYlfk/edit?usp=sharing) for this question since it is about the charts and trendlines, with the randomized input data available to view.

I have a chart that dynamically plots information gathered from a query about sales per week. It plots the sum of $ by week number. It is pulling data live, so that when we get the first sale of a new week, it skews the data significantly.

#### Example:

[image]

The trendline should obviously be positive, but due to next weeks new data adding such a small Y-value, the trendline becomes negative and the chart looks like we are having a major drop in business.

#### Charts & Trendlines (with the newest data manually removed):

[image]

#### Thoughts:

- Manually restricting the chart's input to the past and current week. This shows the chart how I want it, but it doesn't work because I cannot manually go in and update the input range every week.
- Instead of changing the chart, change the main query to ignore values after today(). This may work be a plausible route but it is a very large query and I do not want to run it twice. I have to keep the actual numbers for next week on the screen. I could make a hidden tab and re-run it there how I want and then base the chart off of that tab. *Is this the only option?*
- This is purely an aesthetic presentation problem, so I myself understand why the chart has a drop off, but someone else might take a quick glance and think otherwise. If there are other more efficient or better ways to present such data, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({INDIRECT("Data!A2:D"),WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Data!A2:A"))}, 
 "select Col5,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),count(Col5) 
  where Col1 is not null
    and Col1 < date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "e-m-d")&"' 
  group by Col5"), 
 "offset 1", )), "e")
```

you can get:

[image]

---

### update:

try:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 QUERY({INDIRECT("Data!A2:D"), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Data!A2:A"))}, 
 "select Col5,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),count(Col5) 
  where Col1 is not null group by Col5", ), IFERROR(
 QUERY({INDIRECT("Data!A2:D"), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Data!A2:A"))}, 
 "select Col5,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),count(Col5) 
  where Col1 is not null and Col1 < date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "e-m-d")&"' group by Col5")*SEQUENCE(ROWS(
 QUERY({INDIRECT("Data!A2:D"), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Data!A2:A"))}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col5", )), 1, 1, 0))}, "offset 1", )), "e")
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MMH0fBlEq5VQmO5rIe0tgbGqiW8h3pGhoq6rKe8PExM/copy)

Comment: I already mentioned this option in the 2nd bullet point on the post.

Comment: @Kevin answer updated

Comment: Thank you, awarded. I’m trying to understand the logic behind the use of the sequence function. Can you clarify why this works?

Comment: @Kevin sure. imagine that the output is constructed by 2 tables/queries. first query (on the left side) outputs the whole dataset, while the 2nd query (on the right side) outputs all rows up to today's date so logically its a bit shorter. so if you put it on the scale - left side has more rows & right side has less. if you run it in the cell you will get ARRAYLITERAL_ERROR coz both tables needs to have a same number of rows.

Comment: @Kevin so the idea here is to count how many rows has that larger table and input it into SEQUENCE with 0 stepping so we get arrays of ones which we will multiply with the right table. since all cells are numeric values, `value *1=value`. now we face the situation where our right query has less rows than our sequence of ones we try to multiply it with. this scenario will result in ERRORS coz `no cell*1=error` so we use IFERROR to remove errors so we get the right short query extended on the bottom by array of empty cells to match the row count of the left query